# Are there (non obvious) obstructions for divisibility of sets?

Tags: set-theory

Assume $|A|=\omega $. Assume $\omega_1 \times \omega_2\leq \omega $. Are there $\omega_1$ disjoint subsets of $ A $ each of size $\omega_2$?

Comment: Worst. Notation. EVER.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via the given data there exists an injective map $f\colon \omega_1\times \omega_2\to A$. For each of the $\omega_1$-many $x\in \omega_1$ we have the set $f[\{x\}\times \omega_2]$ of size $\omega_2$.

Comment: ok, sorry, so my question was trivial. I had read about a noncountable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with noncountable complement, and wondered if such things always exist. Apparently the fact that $2\times|\mathbb{R}|\leq |\mathbb{R}|$ and maybe the underlying fact that injection provides an order on sets are the only nontrivial ingredients if one wants to provide such sets by general arguments.